# Restarted computer during update; "the system network service is not compatible with this version"

Tags: wireless, networking, upgrade

Yesterday I upgraded my Ubuntu by SSH but before I finished it, I restarted my computer.
I know that was not very smart. Anyway now I don't have internet connection, the WiFi or Ethernet is not recognized.

When I try on the latest version installed, the mice didn't work. When I try with previous version and go in gnome-network manager it's said:

> The system network service is not compatible with this version

Another thing is when I comeback to the remote computer and look at the SSH terminal the process have stopped at:

```
Setting up desktop-file-utils (0.20-0ubuntu2) ... 
Configuration file `/etc/gnome/defaults.list' 
==> Modified (by you or by a script)
since installation. ==> Package distributor has shipped 
an updated version. What would you like to do about it ? 
Your options are: Y or I:install the package maintainer's 
version N or O : keep your currently-installed version D : 
show the differences between the versions Z : start a shell 
to examine the situation The default action is to keep your 
current version. * defaults.list (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? 
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

Is there any simple solution other than I having to reinstall my system?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If on 14.04 LTS and you are facing problems after update in 2016 or later use this. I updated on 13th May 2016 and started facing this problem. http://askubuntu.com/a/771841/543358 This solved the problem without the need to downgrade.
It will update network manager

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit:** This answer is over six years old and is no longer fresh due to changes in Ubuntu. This is a workaround.

Go into settings, startup items. Add an entry with the following command:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

In a terminal, use `visudo` to add a `NOPASSWD` entry for this command so you do not need to give a password:

```
your-username-here ALL=NOPASSWD: service network-manager start
```

Next time you log on, this will force a start of the network manager (supposing that it is configured such that it can start up).

Comment: It's not a very clean way...

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "clean".

Comment: @jeremiah it's basically a workaround that could be done at a more appropriate time such as one of many initialization boot scripts (although determining which to use is sometimes not trivial)

Comment: [gksu was removed from Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/), so this answer is not helpful for most folks. If you can, just open a command prompt and use sudo.

Comment: @MikeT The problem with the use of pure-sudo is that a startup item probably won't get a proper PTY. I think that the best way to handle this would be to require the NOPASSWD entry so that the command can run fully-automatically.

Answer (score 18):

I faced the same issue. Workaround is to start the network-manager manually

`sudo service network-manager start`

Still trying to figure a way to fix it permanently.

Comment: I haven't found one besides reinstalling :/

Comment: Did you find the permanent way?

Comment: For permanent fix (in ArchLinux) : `sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service` then `sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service`

Answer (score 8):

I had to reinstall the NetworkManager package and reboot. Everything was fine then.

> sudo apt-get --reinstall install network-manager

Comment: thanks @iGeorgie   I am having ubuntu in Virtualbox.. This reinstallation of network manager worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Just stick the following in /etc/rc.local before the line that says "exit":

> NetworkManager

That should launch it whenever your system starts.
A better way would be to add it to the appropriate init scripts so that it doesn't start in single user mode, but honestly it won't hurt anything this way either.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a partially-complete upgrade cause this issue, but my fix was different. Turns out that network-manager won't start at boot if any of the interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces` marked `auto` don't come online. Basically, the static network configuration stuff should all come online before network-manager will be triggered. For me, this was a stray `eth0` configured to use dhcp. I had unplugged the ethernet from my box, and suddenly this problem emerged. Solution was to remove everything but the loopback interface from `/etc/network/interfaces`. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220377/why-doesnt-network-manager-start-at-boot) for more info

Answer (score 3):

My install completed successfully, but I got the same error. Turns out that a new update (which reintroduces an old bug) causes network manager to crash. See here for the fix: [Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)](https://askubuntu.com/q/727127/171608)

Answer (score 2):

If the installation was interrupted, you might get good results by fixing it with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I just had what I think was the same problem OP had, starting manually the Network Manager provided me with the icon in unity, but no interfaces visible, while the above mentioned command and a reboot fixed the issue completely.