# Start hostapd service on boot

Tags: wireless, services, autostart, hostapd

How to start `hostsapd` service every time my compute starts

I have Ubuntu Server 13.10 and kernel 3.11

When I tried `sudo update-rc.d hostapd defaults` I got the following

```
System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/hostapd already exist.
```

and `sudo service hostapd status` shows that the service is not running

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I configure a service to run at startup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup)

Comment: @Parto Already tried that, doesn't work

Comment: Is there anything useful in `/var/log/syslog` after "Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management" if you try `sudo service hostapd start` manually?

Comment: `sudo service hostapd start` works perfectly, my only issue is starting the service automatically @Jos

Comment: Try this: edit the file `/etc/init.d/hostapd`, remove the `--quiet` option in the `start)` section, and reboot. This should give you more informational messages in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Does hostsapd need other services in up status to successfully complete its startup?

Comment: @Letizia I have no idea, how to check that?

Comment: @Jos a message there says that the channel chosen is not supported, but when the computer is on I can use the same configuration file to run the service and it works.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Perhaps report this on Launchpad?

Comment: Run level init process starts ad static-network-up event. The event will not be emitted unless every interface configured as 'auto' in /etc/network/interfaces is up (see this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220377/why-doesnt-network-manager-start-at-boot). Did hostapd need other kind of network up in order to complete its startup? Other point: verify in your /etc/rc2.d the number assigned to Sxxhostapd and which other services has upper value (they start after hostapd). Does this service necessary to hostapd startup? Sorry, but I don't know this service.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have gotten past this, as the daemon reports it is running when querying status.

My `/etc/default/hostapd` file did not define where to find the `hostapd.conf` file (as  provided by Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS).  And so, I received no output when running `sudo service hostapd start` or `sudo service hostapd status`.

Once I directed the out-of-the-box init script to a configuration file, the service was able to start, and show status.

Maybe this was done on purpose to force you to think about configuration before the wireless services start.