# Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, applet

While upgrading today, something caused my wireless network manager to disappear. Not even connecting via wired connection.

This error is being shown by files:

```
**(nm-applet:2716): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files 

(nm-applet:2716): nm-applet-WARNING **: Error connecting to ModemManager: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Cannot launch daemon, file not found or permissions invalid 

(nm-applet:2716): nm-applet-WARNING **: Could not find ShellVersion property on org.gnome.Shell after 5 tries 

(nm-applet:2716): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Is there a patch I can download through windows and send through to my ubuntu, or is it a case of having to reload everything? I tried running two versions back but still no internet access.

Comment: (NetworkManager:2425): GLib-WARNING **: GError set over the top of a previous GError or uninitialized memory. 
This indicates a bug in someone's code. You must ensure an error is NULL before it's set. 
The overwriting error message was: Key file does not have group 'connectivity' 

is what I have encountered trying to restart network manager... went back ten update sets in Ubuntu but still hitting it...

Comment: This problem happened only for those who turned on `proposed` repository. That was initially a bad idea.

Comment: I shall more say that the bad idea was to promote libnl to proposed-updates, without testing it with actual version of network-manager there ...and turning on proposed has a real purpose on a 2 years old lts ubuntu version for targetting *-lts-wily for example, and moreover 3 months before next lts release - anyway, shit happens ;-)

Comment: Just for future reference: "last" upgrade is meaningless when you don't mention what version of Ubuntu you're using and what version of Network Manager you upgraded to.

Comment: I have faced this issue which wasn't got fixed for quite some time. What I do is `sudo ifdown eth0` when disconnected and `sudo ifup eth0` when a new link is connected :) .

Comment: @Pilot6 I had trusty `proposed` updates turned off, but this still happened to me. I don't think that really mattered. The incompatibility was going to happen sooner or later. Like r2rien says, they probably didn't think it and test it through.

Comment: It can happen without `proposed`, but with `proposed` on it is much more likely.

Answer (score 126):

## Cause

This is caused by a regression introduced with a fix for [libnl3 bug #1511735](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1511735).
Resulting network-manager crash has been reported in [network-manager bug #1539513](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1539513) or [network-manager bug #1539634](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1539634)

---

## Solution

Downgrade libnl packages and wait for an upgrade of network-manager package

---

#### Step 1

Try to downgrade libnl with apt-get as in @Max answer:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-route-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-genl-3-200=3.2.21-1
```

#### Step 2

If Step 1 fails,
because the packages aren't anymore in your cache and obviously cannot be downloaded by package manager, you need to downgrade libnl packages manually (download + install):

- Download and copy them to your system
  [ from booting a live distrib/rescue cd or from another computer + usb stick ]
  Download links **for amd64**:
  [libnl](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb)
  [libnl-genl](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb)
  [libnl-route](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb)
  Download links **for i386**:
  [libnl](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_i386.deb)
  [libnl-genl](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_i386.deb)
  [libnl-route](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_i386.deb)
- Back to your system, where you saved these `.deb` files, install them with dpkg:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i libnl-*.deb
  ```

#### Step 3

Now you should be able to (re)start NetworkManager and bring back networking:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

---

## Notice

These bugs hits **ubuntu trusty 14.04 with Pre-released updates** : `trusty-proposed` 
[image: Software Updates properties]

Where last update of libnl packages from version `3.2.21-1` to `3.2.21-1ubuntu1` introduced a regression causing network-manager to crash

---

<del>**There isn't yet any upgrade on network-manager in `trusty-proposed`**

Current version: `0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.2`</del>
**An update of network-manager is now available in `trusty-proposed`**
Updated version: `0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3`
**[please test proposed package (#1539634 comment n°11)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1539634/comments/11)**

---

Thus until an upgrade for it triggers on your package manager you should apply a "hold" - as mentioned in [libnl3 bug #1511735 comment n°29](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1511735/comments/29):

```
sudo apt-mark hold libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200
```

Once the future upgrade from `trusty-proposed` is installed you can remove that hold with:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200
```

Which then will allow you to upgrade again libnl

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! I hope new network-manager package will come out soon. This is a very serious bug..

Comment: If I remember correctly, after installing those three `libnl` packages (at version `3.2.21-1`, not `3.2.21-1ubuntu1`, I did not need to restart the machine. I think I simply reran `sudo /usr/sbin/NetworkManager ` or something like that. Is this correct?  Basically, I'm asking if a reboot is necessary, or if something else is sufficient?

Comment: NetworkManger is a service (but it could depend on your os/version)  
Thus a `sudo service network-manager restart` should be sufficient

Comment: added method to restart network-manager as @AaronMcDaid suggested

Comment: Improved the formatting. I'm also experiencing this and this answer worked for me.

Comment: @r2rien Nice edit! :D

Comment: @laconbass thanks to your greatly improved formatting ;-)

Comment: On your step 2 above, there is another way to do your step 1 that worked for me.  It is using the recovery options in Ubuntu.

1. At the GRuB menu, choose Advanced Options and select the latest Recovery Mode for your latest kernel on your system.

2. In the menu that appears, choose the Enable Network option, and wait until feedback is generated.  Test by pinging a nearby network device.

3.  Choose the Resume option.  Networking should be working but this is temporary.

4.  Do your step 1 above.

5.  Reboot.  Networking should thereafter be working.

Comment: I had the same problem and it took me a long time to get to this question. I was using a live-usb to access wifi and install packages. I couldn't get <b> Step 1</b> to work. <b> Step 2 </b> worked for me. Didn't need reboot.  Thank you!

Comment: Finally found this thread. I even re-installed my laptop's OS. Then my desktop had the same problem. I was crazy!!

Comment: If this bug affected you, please click the two launchpad bug links on the second line and, on the launchpad page click "Yes this bug affects you". Then grab your rotten tomatoes and join my lynch-mob for some misdirected anger. Thanks for this post!

Comment: @r2rien, I'd gladly pay you a beer for this one! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, I was about tho throw a laptop out a window haha. Saved my sanity and laptop.

Comment: I could just fix my fiance's laptop with your help. She loves you now!

Comment: as it looks like the fix (at least for network-manger ;-) is now in thanks to devs, thanks to all !...let's chillout [David Bowie, Live Acoustic "Heroes"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBiiFplMWls)

Comment: yea, new network-manager works like a charm after upgrading the libnl again

Comment: This worked for me! thank you very much. However, I found it weird that it's been more than 3 months since this bug appeared and only now I had the problem. Has the bug been patched? Or should I still apply the hold mentioned above?

Comment: Worked for me. But I checked and guess what, my "proposed" repository is turned off. Looks like after about three months the bug has made its way to more stable repositories.

Comment: Nothing much to add. This one was a life saver. Cheers @r2rien

Comment: I downloaded the files from mobile internet connection. The files are just under 50Kb or so.. and ran the downgrade from the terminal. I restarted the machine and it works fine now.

Comment: After downloading and doing the manual downgrade, I tried the automatic check for updates. There is a new version 3.2.21-1ubuntu1.1 that reverts the incompatible changes, so it appears that placing a hold is not needed. After installing the updates and rebooting, my network still works.

Comment: Downloading these, maybe fiddle the URL to your local mirror rather than rely upon any CDN balancing. Demand is high.

Answer (score 10):

As of **2016-05-13** this [libnl bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1539634/) is affecting also users without **trusty-proposed**, who will almost certainly be directed here by Google.

Updated `libnl` and  `network-manager` packages have already been released, so I recommend a *forward upgrade*.

### Enable Network Manually

Assuming you are using a wired connection, `eth0`and a network with DHCP enabled, configure your network interface using a terminal:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo dhclient eth0
```

### Update network-manager

With the network up and running, do an update either using **Software Updater** or from the terminal using `apt-get`.

#### Option A: Software Updater

Run **Software Updater** and update normally. At the time of writing fixed packages have already been released.

#### Option B: apt-get

(untested). If you want to minimize moving parts or do not have a graphical interface, you can also update from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Comment: thanks so much! I don't have a USB stick around but my desktop does have a wired connection... and this is very helpful.

Comment: +1. Now updated versions of these packages have been released, this is very much the cleanest fix. (Also, confirming that I got hit with this without 'proposed' enabled, and had to grumpily remember how to configure connections with iwconfig before I could get online)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the given solution I want to give a general advice.

## Turn off the "proposed" repository

It is not supposed to be turned on. This "problem" affected only those users who turned on the proposed repository and installed a broken package.

This repository contains testing packages that are not recommended to install unless you want to test some specific packages.

[image]

## Keep "proposed" off if you do not want this kind of surprises.

You can refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49691/what-is-the-proposed-repository) for more information.

Comment: Don't blame users, please. In my opinion it's childishing them and not productive as users could then blame developpers. Better answer is to increase their level of understanding of the system they use, thus their knowledge to how to handle this kind of regression bug

Comment: The users are not supposed to turn this on. The developers fault is to place that checkbox there.

Comment: And this is not a bug. They uploaded a package FOR TESTING, not for usage.

Comment: As a developper, a regression introduced by a fix,
whatever its level of legitimacy - IS a bug.
Could I suggest you chill out a bit, your tone is sounding paternalistic to say the least.
On my side I reworded accordingly my answer. On your side, and at your level, you could have provided some usefull links, like [EnableProposed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/xhttps://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) or [PerformingSRUVerification](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/PerformingSRUVerification) for example

Comment: @r2rien: If you stick to using an LTS, even if there are more recent OS versions available, you aren't not very keen on using 'the latest and greatest' software in the first place. Hence the combination of using an LTS and having -proposed enabled permanently is inconsistent. (I hit the same issue, but I think I have to "blame" myself.) I agree with Pilot6 that this is not a bug. The suffix "-proposed" implies that it's intended for developers and testers.

Comment: I agree that it IS a bug, but in a testing package. The purpose of testing is to find this kind of issues. But if a user does not want to meet this kind of problems "all of a sudden", the repo should be disabled.

Comment: I second this, packages hosted on proposed don't necessarily (and are not expected to) work flawlessly, so if one wants to avoid surprises they have a better chance by turning proposed off.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson don't blame yourself too much, you have more knowledge of what you are doing now :) personally I do this on purpose, as I have more than one OS/version on my system, which was pre-installed with trusty and I want canonical and dell to keep receiving pokes of this

Comment: @Pilot6 (+ @kos) please remember I did mention the `-proposed` context in first place. I understand you might repeat yourself on this subject. In the spirit of your answer last edit: "You can refer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49691/what-is-the-proposed-repository) for more information" - I would suggest you to add your advises directly in my answer, without forgetting about [EnableProposed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) or [PerformingSRUVerification](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/PerformingSRUVerification), this way they should get proper attention ;-)

Comment: I see the bug and @-proposed@ is disabled on my machine, as can be seen here: http://postimg.org/image/c9z0at29z/

Comment: Yes, most users should not have trusty-proposed or trusty-backports enabled.  However, as of today 13 May 2016, apparently the same bug appeared for some people who were _not_ using trusty-backports, requiring manual networking or upgrade of network-manager to 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3.  See [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1581535]

Comment: It did hit me yesterday (May 13, 2016), and when I checked, my "proposed" repository was turned off and the "backport" repository was turned on.

Comment: do I need to make any change here as i do not see the pre-released updates- http://i.imgur.com/PmMbsOC.png?1

Comment: In 16.04 this has been moved to a separate tab. If you never turned it on. you do not need to worry.

Comment: As of May 16, this bug affects general users without this proposed subscription set.

Answer (score 3):

Update to `network-manager 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.2`, and reboot.

Hot workaround: using manual network settings over `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

**Working workaround!**

Downgrade some libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-route-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-genl-3-200=3.2.21-1
```

Comment: That does not provide an answer at all.

Comment: Downgrading libraries may cause other programs to fail - keep that in mind.

Comment: For my system (ElementaryOS, Linux 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu 14.04) downgrade was successful and nm to work again.

Comment: -1 Although this may work on elementary OS, Ubuntu is a different operating system, so a fix may not be compatible.

Comment: This answer is correct. It worked for me with Ubuntu 14.04. I separately downloaded the older versions of three packages (`libnl-`...) and installed them via `dpkg -i`. This morning, my machine had exactly that version (`3.2.21-1`, not `3.2.21-1ubuntu1`) of those three packages listed in the answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem this morning and downgrading the libnl packages worked too.

I rebooted using a rescue CD, downloaded `libnl-3-200-3.2.21-1_amd64.deb`, `libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb` and `libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb` from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/ , installed it using `dpkg -i` and rebooted.

Networking is back. It may not be the ultimate fix, but it got me going on 14.04 for the time being.

Here's the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1539634.

Answer (score 1):

I knew the fix would be out quickly, the tricky part was the chicken and egg issue of getting online. One way is to use wired ethernet which is really easy to get going:

Open a Terminal

```
sudo dhclient eth0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

i am a very very new beginner to ubuntu and that too a non technical man having very little background of this computer languages and all.

i faced the similar problem with nm

as instructed by r2rien i downloaded the three files from the links given by him

(first i could not understand that they are three links but thanks to his precise use of english: the word "files" made me look up again and i downloaded the rest two files)

then i could not install it

i was not able to understand the asterisk in "sudo dpkg -i libnl-*.deb"

how much ever i tried to install first files individually, then together, then by apt-get; sometime interchanging = in place of _ like 3-200=3.2.21-1 in place of 3-200_3.2.21-1. still no result. searched on net then found out very easy way of doing it. by dragging the file in terminal after "sudo dpkg -i "

then encountered another problem: processing triggers...
that too as someone gave suggestion by just "enter and then username and enter" got it solved. was skeptical still.
finally it worked. thanks r2rien and friends.

Comment: The asterisk in 'libnl-*.deb' is a wildcard, so that command will affect anything that starts with "libnl-" and ends with ".deb". 

As a side note: on StackExchange communities, it's good to put messages like this that are comments on other people's solutions in the comments, rather than as answers in themselves.