# Ubuntu 14.04+all current updates. Networking stopped working

Tags: networking

Running latest 14.04 plus all fixes up to and including 28th Jan 2016, all network connectivity gone on re-boot. My guess is it was the last lot of updates which where some lib files.

Installed files which might be the problem:

```
network-manager-gnome 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.4
libnm-util2 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.2.
```

It might be `libnm-util` was in the last update set but not sure. This is a very serious problem.  How can I fix this without network connectivity?

Comment: Why people keep answering this for wireless, when this is a problem about the wired connection?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here (Ubuntu 14.04LTS)!
Please notice, there is already a different thread [#727127](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127).

While this does not fix the problem, for me it helped to do a manual configuration of the wlan interface, e.g. to edit

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

I followed the example given [here](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/230-ubuntu-setup-wifi-commandline) (see 3.2). The page gives some other information and additional steps, which were not necessary in my case.

/etc/network/interfaces:

> auto wlan0
>   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
>   wpa-driver wext
>   wpa-ssid *your_network_ssid*
>   wpa-psk *your_network_psk*
>   # if your SSID is hidden, change value to 2
>   wpa-ap-scan 1
>   # type WPA for WPA1, RSN for WPA2
>   wpa-proto RSN
>   # type CCMP for AES, TKIP for TKIP
>   wpa-pairwise CCMP
>   # type CCMP for AES, TKIP for TKIP
>   wpa-group CCMP
>   # type WPA-PSK for shared key (most common), WPA-EAP for enterprise radius server
>   wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK

I simply adjusted the settings for wpa-ssid and wpa-psk followed by a reboot.
With that, at least I got a working wifi connection back.
And I can hope now for a fix, which I will be able to download, when it becomes available.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: you need to restart the interface `sudo service network-interface restart INTERFACE=wlan0`

Answer (score 1):

It's an upgrade bug.
As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/upgrade-made-all-network-manager-and-wireless-disappear-in-ubuntu-this-morning), you have to downgrade some packages to have your network working again...
Hope that Ubuntu Staff will solve the problem soon.

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-route-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-genl-3-200=3.2.21-1
```

It worked like a charm for me on Ubuntu 14.04. Hope that help. Rgds

Comment: well to do this, we need a connection right?

Comment: Yes, but there is a way that worked for me: boot in rescuemode, choose network connection and then choose resume boot. Strangely enough I had a working network after that. Which in turn let me downgrade the packages :-)

Answer (score 0):

you will need the ISO image of Ubuntu

Insert cdrom Ubuntu

Go to Unity Dash and look for Software & Updates

In the first tab Ubuntu Software, check the option of CD Rom with Ubuntu

Next is to go in Additional Drivers tab and select the propriety driver and click on Apply Changes

Once the drivers have been installed, you’ll see that Ubuntu now recognizes the wireless networks in range.

Comment: Thanks for that but it is not the lack of WiFi but of cable networking ie ethernet, I don't have WiFi on the machine. Prior to 28th Jan update (from ubuntu), cable networking worked, now it doesn't.  Network Manager gui shows a red "X" and no devices.

Comment: instal '' sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)'' next step "sudo apt-get install wpa_supplicant" networkmanager is the gui of wpa-supplicant

Comment: You can see if your wireless drivers are activated in the kernel and that your card is detected in Linux with the command: " ifconfig -a "

Comment: Packages updates on 28/29th (it was late) from: cat /var/log/dpkg.log include : 
libnl-3-200:amd64 3.2.21-1ubuntu1 
libnl-route-3-200:amd64 3.2.21-1ubuntu1
 libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 3.2.21-1ubuntu1

Are these the problem?

Comment: we need collect info about wifi card and firmware

Comment: apt search wpasupplicant and iwconfig = resutl ??

Comment: $ apt search wpasupplicant

wpasupplicant/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 2.1-0ubuntu1.4 amd64 [installed]

  client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)

$ iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  

          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   

          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off

          Power Management:on

Comment: (sudo modprobe wl ), (ifconfig wlan0 down )and (ifconfig wlan0 up ), (dhclient wlan0)

Comment: All wlan0 etc commands fail as THERE IS NO WiFi device fitted to machine. This is not a WiFi problem but a WIRED LAN problem.  Hope that makes it clear. Help much appreciated.

Comment: thank you, iwconfig fails >> you need to install wireless tools >> sudo aptitude install wireless-tools

Comment: I'm not sure where this is going. I can't install wireless-tools as I don't have any network connection at all, ie no WIRED LAN.  I can see how I can do this using another machine but it's not clear to me why I should be trying to install WiFi when I don't have such a device, or is the process to recovering my WIRED lan more subtle than I might have thought?

Comment: i am sorry to give u some solutions no needed , how to config wired connexion manually https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-manual.html