# Network manager issue: The system network services are not compatible with this version

Tags: networking, network-manager, compatibility

I have seen relevant solutions in askubuntu and other sites but none worked for me so far.

I reinstalled network manager, modem manager, tried to upgrade them and manually install everything, also tried nm-applet solution. But nothing seems to be working. The network manager icon is not there and normal reboot has no networking option. I have also gone to recovery and enabled networking via Ethernet and then resumed normal boot. But again after reboot there is not networking option. No WiFi, no Ethernet.

Can someone please help me out? Reinstalling will definitely solve this but all my settings and work will be gone and it is painful to set up again. So folks here please suggest me what to do.

Comment: What's the the output of `lsb_release -a`, `uname -rm` and `apt-cache policy network-manager`?

Comment: If you upgraded libnl packages recently, maybe you can try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/upgrade-made-all-network-manager-and-wireless-disappear-in-ubuntu-this-morning).

Answer (score 13):

Get onto a working machine (or plug into internet using an Ethernet cable)  and download these three packages ... they are the working versions prior to recent broken release :

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
```

once downloaded copy onto a memory stick or similar then transfer onto your broken ubuntu box ... then install :

```
sudo dpkg -i libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
```

reboot and your Wifi will be back working ... enjoy

Comment: I had reinstalled OS. But thanks for your sincere assistance

Comment: You are awesome :)

Comment: Thank you sir!The same solution worked for me under 14.04 for Ethernet connection. The latest update from Ubuntu broke the network manager.