# 14.04--Routine update killed network-manager, unable to connect to any networks

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, compatibility

I am running 14.04 LTS on a Dell XPS 13 9343.  Today I did a routine update through Software Updater and restarted when it prompted me.  When I logged back in I had no internet connection and no icon in the menu bar to edit connections.  When I open "Network" within the main Settings menu, I get the message:

```
The system network services are not compatible with this version
```

When I open the "Network Connections" dialog, all options are greyed out. I have attempted to connect to Ethernet as well as WiFi to no avail.

Please help, I am freaking out. This is the machine I use for my job and doing a fresh install of Ubuntu would be a massive hassle as I have all kinds of specialized software packages installed.

I should also mention that I tried reinstalling `network-manager`. I even removed and purged it, then reinstalled from the package provided on the Ubuntu website. That didn't change anything. I also purged and reinstalled the network-manager-gnome package to see if I could fix the GUI issues (`nm-applet` not working) but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: A similar issue has been reported [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/727431/network-manager-issue-the-system-network-services-are-not-compatible-with-this).

Comment: I solved this problem like explained AnotherVictim. But for the future you should block version of this packages or disable "proposed" upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I could recover from the same problem by downgrading *to* the following packages (assuming the 64-bit version):

1. libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
2. libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
3. libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb

From a device with internet access download the above packages (e.g from packages.ubuntu.com) and find a way to transfer them to your computer.
Install them with

```
    dpkg -i *.deb
```

After a reboot everything should work again.