# Ubuntu 14.04 Unable to connect to internet

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

All of a sudden, I am unable to connect to ethernet... the network manager icon doesn't appear anymore

It used to work perfectly and the ethernet cable is working with another PC.

Here is what I get with ifconfig:

```
lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
  inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
  adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  Packets reçus:10544 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:10544 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
  Octets reçus:811701 (811.7 KB) Octets transmis:811701 (811.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:51:b7:00:d5:66  
  UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  Packets reçus:0 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
  Octets reçus:0 (0.0 B) Octets transmis:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:51:b7:00:d5:66  
  inet adr:169.254.8.18  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Masque:255.255.0.0
  UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu just had a major glitch.
One of the last updated caused you & me and probably many others to stay disconnected because network-manager is crashing.
This is a major glitch since now users are disconnected from the internet and cannot get the fix for this problem.

Open a terminal and type

```
grep network-manager /var/log/syslog.*
```

If you see errors like this one:

> init: network-manager main process (1318) killed by SEGV signal

Than you're affected by this bug.
You'll have to connect manually without network manager and update the system again with

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you have an ethernet card than you can simply do

```
sudo dhclient -v eth0
```

to restore your connection,
Then run the apt-get commands above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this it worked for me , try downloading these package and install(download from device with internet access).

```
libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
```

and after downloading go to directory where the packages are stored
write the command

```
 dpkg -i *.deb
```

all the best. you can find here [14.04--Routine update killed network-manager, unable to connect to any networks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727447/14-04-routine-update-killed-network-manager-unable-to-connect-to-any-networks)