# Wifi connection problem after updating

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, compatibility

The thing is that I need some help with my Ubuntu 14.04. After running an update and rebooting my system, I am not able to connect to WiFi or any other networks. It says:

> The system network services are not compatible with this version.

Comment: Similar issues have been reported [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/727447/14-04-routine-update-killed-network-manager-unable-to-connect-to-any-networks) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/727431/network-manager-issue-the-system-network-services-are-not-compatible-with-this).

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/129436/restarted-computer-during-update-the-system-network-service-is-not-compatible

Comment: This problem happens only to stupid people who have enabled `proposed` repository. Some unstable package has been installed.

Comment: This is not duplicate but a new issue not related to the duplicate link above  (as another user stated yesterday but its answer  was removed )  , see http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet