# The network manager nm-applet has disappeared from the panel of my Ubuntu 14.04 and I don´t have connection to internet

Tags: network-manager

When I try to run it from the command line, I receive an error:

```
** (nm-applet:2403): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

(nm-applet:2403): nm-applet-WARNING **: Error connecting to ModemManager: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Cannot launch daemon, file not found or permissions invalid

(nm-applet:2403): nm-applet-WARNING **: Could not find ShellVersion property on org.gnome.Shell after 5 tries

(nm-applet:2403): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/upgrade-made-all-network-manager-and-wireless-disappear-in-ubuntu-this-morning

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Then type in `nm-applet` and press enter

This should work.