# NetworkManager error

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

I do not know specifications of this error. All I know is about usr/sbin/NetworkManager

I do not have internet, any network or applet.

What can I do to give you mor information of solve this?

Grazie.

all ready tried:
Sudo NetworkManager restart
And restart de applet
Purge and install NetworkManager again, with all depends it's need.
Not worked

Comment: I believe you need to try this instead: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: "Stop: unknown instance: network-manager start/running, process 2544" but nothing else happens, still no network working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! :)

Downloaded "libnl libnl-genl libnl-route" from other computer. And installed.

Here solution by steps:
[Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)

Thanks community!