# Wifi doesn't work after upgrading Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 and after that networking option disappeared. I can access to internet with network cable but Wifi doesn't work!
I see this results:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ####

Linux 3.13.0-77-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 10:50:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, recovery, nomodeset

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci ####

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8172] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Quanta Microsystems, Inc Device [1a32:0308]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1063] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device [152d:0831]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 064e:a118 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d8d:0516 Promotion & Display Technology, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 18e8:6252 Qcom 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6367819  0 
rtl8192se              63196  0 
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8192se
mxm_wmi                13021  0 
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192se
mac80211              630728  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192se
cfg80211              484040  3 wl,mac80211,rtlwifi
wmi                    19177  1 mxm_wmi

##### interfaces 

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.113.251  Bcast:192.168.115.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:130918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70677 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:118852197 (118.8 MB)  TX bytes:5263436 (5.2 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.112.99  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.112.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 192.168.1.2
nameserver 192.168.1.3

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

    None found.

##### NetworkManager info ###############

** (process:10337): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

** (process:10337): WARNING **: error: could not connect to NetworkManager

NetworkManager Tool

State: unknown

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true

##### NetworkManager profiles ###

Sorry, try again.
[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot-98e1e41d-fa36-453f-b4bc-7e2b15eca485]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Hotspot | type=802-11-wireless | autoconnect=false
[802-11-wireless] ssid=saleh-Q1585N | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=shared
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless C1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless C1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless C1 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Bazarbors.com]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Bazarbors.com | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Bazarbors.com | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=salehhotspot | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ansar]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ansar | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Ansar | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/farhangi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=farhangi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=farhangi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Library]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Library | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Library | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Kanoon]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Kanoon | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Kanoon | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/hp1390]] (600 root)
[connection] id=hp1390 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=hp1390 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Drsanaat]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Drsanaat | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Drsanaat | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless W-4]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless W-4 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless W-4 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless W2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless W2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless W2 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TP-LINK-turk]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TP-LINK-turk | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=TP-LINK-turk | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/saleh-Q1585N 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=saleh-Q1585N 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=saleh-Q1585N | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/saleh]] (600 root)
[connection] id=saleh | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=saleh | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless C3]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless C3 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless C3 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Tenda_44E711]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Tenda_44E711 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Tenda_44E711 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WUMUP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WUMUP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=WUMUP | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless W-1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless W-1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless W-1 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/bscmath]] (600 root)
[connection] id=bscmath | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=bscmath | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Acari Wireless C2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Acari Wireless C2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Acari Wireless C2 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/farhangi 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=farhangi 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=farhangi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless C-3]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless C-3 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless C-3 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless C-1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless C-1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless C-1 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/saleh-Q1585N]] (600 root)
[connection] id=saleh-Q1585N | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=saleh-Q1585N | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless W1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless W1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless W1 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Hotspot | type=802-11-wireless | autoconnect=false
[802-11-wireless] ssid=saleh-Q1585N | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=shared
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Acari Wireless C-2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Acari Wireless C-2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Acari Wireless C-2 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless E-2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless E-2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless E-2 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Asari Wireless E-1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Asari Wireless E-1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Asari Wireless E-1 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MobinnetHedayati]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MobinnetHedayati | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MobinnetHedayati | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MobinnetHedayati 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MobinnetHedayati 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MobinnetHedayati | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Tehran (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels 

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan 

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

##### module infos 

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-77-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     3F8570547EE3A2BA3D5D734
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       3.13.0-77-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[rtl8192se]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-77-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192sefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192S/8191S 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     C53951858E34882052195CA
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-77-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D9:61:BD:20:E8:AC:66:64:3F:C6:DC:2D:56:66:8F:42:6E:33:E8:8F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-77-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     D5E4890DC428FA5A1BF92DF
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-77-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D9:61:BD:20:E8:AC:66:64:3F:C6:DC:2D:56:66:8F:42:6E:33:E8:8F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-77-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     730FEE1A7696EA37A982482
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-77-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D9:61:BD:20:E8:AC:66:64:3F:C6:DC:2D:56:66:8F:42:6E:33:E8:8F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-77-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     05D0444BE5CC949584FB8E4
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-77-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D9:61:BD:20:E8:AC:66:64:3F:C6:DC:2D:56:66:8F:42:6E:33:E8:8F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-77-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     695424C2F5CD23A91B67E25
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-77-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D9:61:BD:20:E8:AC:66:64:3F:C6:DC:2D:56:66:8F:42:6E:33:E8:8F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters ##

[rtl8192se]
debug: 0
fwlps: N
ips: Y
swenc: N
swlps: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules #

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options 

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist acer_wmi

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local 

exit 0

##### pm-utils #

##### udev rules #

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0x1063 (atl1c)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8172 (rtl8192se)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

## dmesg 

[  985.608872] init: network-manager main process (8207) killed by SEGV signal
[  985.608887] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  985.618968] traps: NetworkManager[8351] general protection ip:469fee sp:7fff0cc06810 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  985.785606] init: network-manager main process (8351) killed by SEGV signal
[  985.785621] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  985.795162] traps: NetworkManager[8361] general protection ip:469fee sp:7ffd42a45200 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  985.943336] init: network-manager main process (8361) killed by SEGV signal
[  985.943351] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  985.953564] traps: NetworkManager[8367] general protection ip:469fee sp:7ffe29768190 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  986.103293] init: network-manager main process (8367) killed by SEGV signal
[  986.103309] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  986.113467] traps: NetworkManager[8372] general protection ip:469fee sp:7ffeab442de0 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  986.266190] init: network-manager main process (8372) killed by SEGV signal
[  986.266205] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  986.276021] traps: NetworkManager[8377] general protection ip:469fee sp:7fffdbc12150 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  986.427637] init: network-manager main process (8377) killed by SEGV signal
[  986.427654] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  986.437833] traps: NetworkManager[8398] general protection ip:469fee sp:7ffe0e67a0a0 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  986.588523] init: network-manager main process (8398) killed by SEGV signal
[  986.588540] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  986.598369] traps: NetworkManager[8403] general protection ip:469fee sp:7ffff9e42650 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  986.745616] init: network-manager main process (8403) killed by SEGV signal
[  986.745633] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  986.755427] traps: NetworkManager[8408] general protection ip:469fee sp:7fffd1dd00a0 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  986.904479] init: network-manager main process (8408) killed by SEGV signal
[  986.904498] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  986.914158] traps: NetworkManager[8415] general protection ip:469fee sp:7fff67e25380 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  987.065235] init: network-manager main process (8415) killed by SEGV signal
[  987.065251] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[  987.075175] traps: NetworkManager[8420] general protection ip:469fee sp:7ffc01db44c0 error:0 in NetworkManager[400000+10d000]
[  987.226631] init: network-manager main process (8420) killed by SEGV signal
[  987.226646] init: network-manager respawning too fast, stopped
[  989.758357] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:84:38:38:0e:aa:b4:08:00 SRC=192.168.113.229 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22268 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50990 DPT=80 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[ 1127.706897] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37726 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1127.964737] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37731 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1127.972500] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.177 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=42388 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1127.973716] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37733 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1128.011773] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=216.58.211.1 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37901 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1129.002954] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37724 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1129.040806] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37734 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1129.064828] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37736 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1129.661883] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37739 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1129.682656] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37740 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1146.585719] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:00:21:70:dd:9d:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.113.170 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=7723 PROTO=UDP SPT=64280 DPT=7 LEN=9 
[ 1193.277351] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:00:21:70:dd:9d:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.113.170 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=8188 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53966 DPT=2987 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[ 1196.279011] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:00:21:70:dd:9d:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.113.170 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=8201 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53966 DPT=2987 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[ 1202.282086] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:00:21:70:dd:9d:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.113.170 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=8208 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53966 DPT=2987 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[ 1254.908020] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37819 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1254.929920] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37820 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1254.949806] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=94.20.252.183 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=37821 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1274.146329] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=31.13.93.3 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=47319 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1274.233523] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>:88:f0:77:ca:11:42:08:00 SRC=31.13.93.3 DST=192.168.113.251 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=47323 WINDOW=27 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
[ 1364.957607] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:fb:48:9d:24:da:32:d1:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a9d:24ff:feda:32d1 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:00fb LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=131 CODE=0  (repeated 16 times)
```

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: Same by me. Two previous kernels also stopped serving wifi. Seems like some key app's changed.

Comment: The network menu icon in the top belt's gone for good too.

Comment: It will be related to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet/727204#727204

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks I done your requested edit.

Comment: @Tomasz Thanks but I done all of this workd! But it not helps!

Comment: The in-kernel wireless driver seems to be exactly the right one for your device. But NetworkManager crashed a bunch of times. Is your system updagred (`apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgraded`)? It may also be worthwhile to switch to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.3 and kernel 3.19 or 4.2.

Comment: Are you sure the versions are these: sudo apt-get install libnl-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-route-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-genl-3-200=3.2.21-1
 This fix worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Make sure you don't update everything after you've downgraded these ones, as they will upgrade again.

Comment: And don't forget to reboot.

Comment: @david Foerster Thanks! +1 for I find out that there's some deleted repositories in apt list that avoid updating. after update I run: `Exec=nm-applet` and then `Exec=dbus-launch nm-applet` and then My saved wifi connected! But there isn't any network manager Icon in ubuntu panel yet! can you help me for this too?

Comment: @Tomasz thanks for your trying for me, But sorry! they are same version as you said!