# What is causing my networking to fail to start on startup?

Tags: networking

I turned on my computer yesterday, logged in, started up Chrome and found an error message stating I had no internet connection. I fixed it temporarily by running

```
sudo ifcongifg eth0 up
sudo dhclient eth0
```

However, I'd like to find out what caused this sudden change in behaviour, and how to fix it. I've been running 14.04 for over 16 months now, and this is the first I've encountered this problem.
Thanks~

Comment: We need more information about your system -- did you install/uninstall/update any packages? Did any configs change? What do your logfiles say?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I checked the output of dmesg and found that network-manager was repeatedly crashing. I then searched around and found the answer here:

[Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)

Downgrading libnl and restartring network-manager seems to have worked