# Network disabled Ubuntu 14.04 after update and steps to resolve

Tags: wireless

Without duplicating questions... I have the same wifi issue with 14.04 after an update. I've tried the posted solutions (including downloading and downgrading the version), my network-manager as a process works ("network-manager start/running, process 2727"), yet when I go to "System settings - Network", I got the same window: "The system network services are not compatible with this version". 
I've run "lshw -C network" and it looks like both my Ethernet ans wireless interfaces are disabled, yet my airplane mode is OFF. 
Is there anything else I could do? Thanks!

My wireless network Adapter is QCA9565/AR9565 and the configuration is: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.19.0-49-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

Comment: I think I had the same problem. The following post provided a solution that worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet It requires you to downgrade libnl and suggests unchecking 'Pre-released updates' in the Software & Updates settings.

Comment: I've done it prior to my post and it didn't work. Looks like there is a command which keeps my network adapters disabled.

Comment: Hmm ... well, have you come across and tried this forum post?

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172044&p=12777826#post12777826