# Ubuntu 14.04 Network Manager is not available after Sw-Update

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

After running a regular Sw-update this morning, and restarting my Lenovo T430-based Ubuntu 14.04, the Network Icon on my Gnome2-panel is all grey and on left-clicking on it, it says: NetworkManager is not running.
I tried to start the service manually from a terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But this only returned:

```
stop: Unknown instance:
network-manager start/running, process 5174
```

Needless to say, the network-icon in my gnome-panel remained grey and
no internet-connection was established. And then, while trying to kill this process 5174 with:

```
kill 5174
```

the terminal returned:

```
bash: kill: (5174) - No such process
```

What's going on here ?
Any advice how to get online again ?

Comment: I am online again.
This other post from three days ago actually did provide the right solution:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet
Thank you very much everybody. Great experience with Ask Ubuntu !
Kind regards // Frank

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this, and enter in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
```

and then reboot, and it might work fine this way.