# Wired connection (eth0) is working but network manager icon shows no network

Tags: 14.04, updates, network-manager

After updating my `network-manager`, my wired **connection continued to work**, but it shows no notification; the double arrow is also missing, and the network manager just shows that "no connection" icon. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)

Comment: @Pilot6, not a duplicate. Connection was working fine, just the notification was off.

Comment: But the problem and the solution must be the same I guess.

Comment: @Pilot6 I appreciate the effort to avoid duplications on the site, but aside from restarting the network manager (which is not part of the solution, just a shortcut for a computer restart), I don't see similarities between the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `NetworkManager.conf` file. One of these two commands should work, depending on your Ubuntu version (the first command worked in my 14.04 installarion).

```
gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf
```

The opened document should have these lines:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Change them to:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Finally, you need to restart your `network-manager`. Do this at the terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1079394