# Xubuntu 14.0.3 lost all network connectivity

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04.3 on a Lenovo G50-70 updated earlier today, but I don't think any updates to the Kernel.  I shut the laptop down, and had to leave for a wile.

When I turned the unit back on when I came back, I noticed that there were no network connectivity, either wired or wireless.  If I try to add a connection through network manager, I can't since all is grayed out.

[image]

[image]

If I try to do `sudo service network-manager restart` I get

[image]

Even the network indicator has disappeared.  How can this be fixed.

I tried the fix [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet), and it fixed it.