# Ethernet not working or even showing up. 14.04 LTS. Dell Inspirion E1505

Tags: networking, ethernet

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Inspirion E1505 and when I booted to the install drive it recognized the Internet just fine. Now that I have it installed, not so much. When I run `ifconfig` it only returns `lo`. When I run:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

it only returns:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: if you run `apt-cache policy network-manager` and the version installed, denoted by prepended `***`, is from `trusty-proposed` and is at version `0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.2`, you could add `14.04` tag and check if your question is a duplicate of [#727127](http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems in the past. Often adding `auto eth0` to the end of `/etc/network/interfaces` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo lshw -C network` shows that you have an `eth0` (You may have to `sudo apt-get instal lshw`), add `iface eth0 inet` to `/etc/network/interfaces`