# Update made my network stop working and receiving internal error message

Tags: networking, updates

I was notified with a bunch of updates just half an hour ago, mostly security updates in nature. Without thinking much I authenticated the installation. It required me to reboot to apply the changes. After reboot I noticed that the network was not working. Please check the image below.

[The error I'm getting on network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcn90.png)

Also on restarting again I got a error message that Ubuntu has faced an internal error. Since my network is not working I couldn't send the crash report to Ubuntu. Please check the screenshot below.

[The internal error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15GYq.png)

I'm new to Ubuntu. Just a 1 week old user. I think if I can somehow revert back the Wi-Fi update, i.e., backport it may help to solve the situation. But I don't know how to or if that's the only solution. Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the GUI error messages, but since you're on 14.04 it's likely your problem is the same as this one: [Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/upgrade-made-all-network-manager-and-wireless-disappear-in-ubuntu-this-morning)

Check `/var/log/apt/history.log` and if the recent updates included `libnl libnl-genl libnl-route` then it is the same problem and you can find the answer at the link above.