# Network is not connected

Tags: networking, network-manager

After updating some data my system is not shown the Wifi option any more and it does not detect the network if I insert the wired cable.

I already tried these attempts:

1. `etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.cfg`

   ```
   [main] plugins=ifupdown,keyfile dns=dnsmasq

   [ifupdown] managed=false
   ```
2. `/etc/network/interfaces`, comment out everything other than:

   ```
   auto lo iface lo inet loopback
   ```
3. I deleted a `pid` file from `/var/run/dbus`

Still I cant get the internet option. It's irritating me. Can anyone give me the solution for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)

Comment: Do not turn on the `proposed` repository and you will not get irritated again.