# Can I get some help with my wifi?

Tags: internet

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot with Windows 7. My wifi inexplicably stopped working today and I have no idea why. It works fine in Windows. I really like Ubuntu but I'm afraid I'm not very computer savvy. Can anyone offer some suggestions or advice. I'll provide all the answers you need to some this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Try sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces and show what you get

Comment: This is what I got:  # interfaces(5) file used by ifup (8) and ifdown (8) auto lo I face lo inet loopback

Comment: this is not whole output....there is more right?

Comment: copy everything and paste it here http://paste.ofcode.org/  and click down on [Paste it   Enter] button on that website and copy the url address and post it here

Comment: No. That's exactly what came up.

Answer (score -1):

Today many people are having this problem in Ubuntu, after an upgrade it seems that Network Manager is crashing. I solved it with this tutorial

[Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. But I tried both step 1 and step 2 and I still couldn't get it to work.