# How to get my disappeared network connection to work again?

Tags: 14.04, networking

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a laptop. Suddenly my Network possibilities have disappeared. (No network connection and no show of the network icons or in control panel) The laptop has a fixed ethernet connection and a working wifi (802.11g).

So far I have tried several things, but can not get it working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit to include output of `lsusb` and `lspci`.

Comment: @Andriod Dev : here are the lsusb and lspcihow can I put them in? I cannot attatch png here, or how can I copy from the terminal, I haven't figured this out yet...

Comment: Just click and drag in the terminal, and then copy & paste it in your answer.

Comment: bettina@BS-laptop:~$ lspci00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LC Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller

Comment: these are the needed ones, I guess. The file is a little too big for the comment field

Comment: I believe the problem is exactly what @Albert described, however, I wasn't lucky in executing the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found an old thread:

[Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)

After downgrading libnl I could restart the network manager.

Later, Ubuntu obviously suggested upgrading again libnl but also other packages. I did it and everything works.

Comment: Thanks, I have found this thread myself and tried, it did not work as expected. Maybe because, I am a novice user or maybe it didn't work. In any case, unfortunately, I still have the problem