# No internet connection after software update on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, update-manager

I am using ubuntu 14.04 for quite a while and never had this problem. But last time that I updated it, it lost its internet connection. It is a PC and I am just using wired connection. I saw several posts about it, usually they upgraded from another version to 14.04, and the answer didn't help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Press **ctrl+alt+T** and paste in:
Code:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Remove everything and paste the code given below in the file

Code:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then Check /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf

Press **ctrl+alt+T** and paste in:

Code:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf
```

and set file with code shown below

Code:

```
 [ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Restart computer or NetworkManager service.

For more info See: [Network manager](http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager)

Hope this solves

Comment: When I run `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` on the terminal, I am getting this error Gtk-Warning **: calling ingibit failed : GDBus.Error:org.freedestop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: Have u installed sudo. Else open **synaptic package manager** and search for sudo, mark it and install it. Then try the above provided step

Comment: if the above fails then replace all occurrences of sudo with gksudo. You can install gksudo by typing the command **apt-get install gksu**

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same procedure that is mentioned here:

[Last upgrade crashes network manager (no internet connection, no applet)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)

I thought it is not related to my problem because I haven't upgraded my Ubuntu just was doing regular updating. But I tried it and it worked. I downloaded libnl files on another computer and copied them to my system by USB. 
It was pretty straight forward!