# network interface not found; services network-manager missing

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, dell

**EDIT: [New Update Crashes network manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)
My question is a duplicate to some extent; the answer there din not solve my problem**

I got this weird problem where my machine cannot find any networking. Not even the wi-fi symbol appears on the taskbar. $service network-manager stop unrecognized command.

**machine:** Dell Inspiron 5551 version A03

**os:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (came with the laptop from factory)

**Story:**
I ran the update it got stuck for an hour and a half on installing grub update;
I rebooted-> Critical Error.
Reinstalled OS from factory image. It got stuck at the end at the logs 1 hour passes. 
I rebooted->it worked but it cannot find the network hardware.
I tryed to install a different version of ubuntu but during the installation it said it could not set up a network and it is recommended that I go back on the previous step. 
I aborted the new installation, currently running the os I have mentioned under the machine.

On startup under Ubuntu loading screen: Waiting for network configuration; Waiting up to 60 seconds for network configuration...

I have lurked a bit on google on similar related problems but I could not manage to troubleshoot it.

I have decided to ask for help here, can anyone help me find a solution to my problem and make the networking work again so I can connect to the internet?

**$sudo lshw -c network**

*-network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless 3160
vendor: Intel Corporation
logical name: wlan0
version: 83
driverversion=3.13.0-38

**$iwconfig**

lo no wireless extensions

wlan0 IEEE 802.11abgn ESSID:off/any
      Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=0 dNm
      Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on

**$dmesg | grep -i iwlagn**

nothing -> So i guess here is the problem. No driver;

**EDIT**

**$dmesg | iwl**

iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 106 for MSI/MSI-X
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 23.214.9.0 op_mode iwlmbm
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Inter(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S

**/etc/network/interfaces**

added the following lines:

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

**$sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0**

Listening on LPF/wlan0:34:de:1a:9c:bd:af
Sending on LPF/wlan0:34:de:1a:9c:bd:af
Sending on Socket/fallback
ifup: failed to open lockfile /run/network/.ifstate.lock: Permission denied

found this [bug fix-up](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1072518) for the Permission denied encountered earlier.

**$sudo restart networking**

-> restart: Job failed to restart

**$sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart.**

nothing happened
apparently i got other bug

**$sudo nmcli nm enable false**

process:2916: WARNING: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

**Found this: [New Update Crashes network manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)
My question is a duplicate to some extent**

The problem still persists. Got errors when installing libnl. Managed to use apt-get -f install the wireless symbol appeared on the taskbar but the Wi-Fi networks otpion is gray and cant be selected, same with device not managed;

answer to user **chili555**

**$rfkill list all**

0: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked:no Hard blocked:no
1: hci0: Bluetooth: Soft blocked:no Hard blocked:no

**$lsmod | grep dell**

dell_led
dell_wmi
sparse_keymap
dell_laptop
dcdbas
wmi

**Did a reboot** 
Now the wireless symbol does not show anymore on the taskbar.

**Locally downloaded network-manager.deb**
installed network-manager got the following errors:
dpkg: error processing package network-manager
locale: cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: no scuh file or directory
locale: same of LC_messages and LC_All

report for **chili555**: I reverted the changes to /etc/network/interfaces did a reboot now no longer said waiting for network while ubuntu loaded but no wifi symbol in taskbar.

pastebin for **chili555**: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23129565/ refering to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180)

**EDIT2**

Tryed running in safe mode -> mount network -> Segmentation fault

Now I am trying to revert to factory image. Failed.

Doing a clean install of ubuntu 16.0.4.1 erased everything -> all working fine now. But the problem has not been solved, had to reinstall.

Comment: Probably you need to install some drivers package from Dell. But, considering you're reinstalling, why not test the current LTS - 16.04 -? Chances are it will just work.

Comment: I unfortunately cant find the drivers packages from Dell :<
Maybe I will give a try to the new LTS after I try to fix this.

Comment: That's service, not services, right?

Comment: yes service network-manager restart -> network-manager: unrecognized service

Comment: Disabled usually means the switch or key combination is set to disable wireless. What does this tell us? `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod | grep dell`

Comment: @chili555 I have edited the title as it might be missleading, added the commands in the answer.

Comment: You have all the drivers and firmware you require. I suggest that you revert the changes to `/etc/network/interfaces` as they are incorrect. Reboot and report.

Comment: I reverted the changes to /etc/network/interfaces did a reboot now no longer said waiting for network while ubuntu loaded but no wifi signal in taskbar

Comment: Please paste the diagnostic wireless_script: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 As it will be lengthy, paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44879/discussion-between-m-f-crist-and-chili555).

Comment: Are you in chat? I'm waiting.