# nm applet crash [MATE 16.04.2]

Tags: network-manager, ubuntu-mate

So rigth after installing Ubuntu MATE from a usb i got an error message saying that the nm applet crashed.

Now the wifi connections icon is not displayed and i can't seem to find any other way to acces the internet.

I've read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet) answers but i'm really hesitant to try them,because of it being a bug from a year ago and mine came out of a fresh installation.
I'm a noob when it comes to linux,this being my first distro after a failed attempt at using elementaryOS,**so forgive me if this sounds like i'm just looking to be spoonfed a solution**.

*P.S : I can use wifi without problems with windows and i was able to use it with elementary*

Is there a way of fixing this bug permanently?
Does it have something to do with my wifi chip or is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: The bug referred to in that post has been marked as "Fix Released" in Trusty, and therefore should not be relevant now on a 16.04 "Xenial" release.

Comment: I would recommend opening a terminal and restarting network-manager with `sudo service network-manager restart`.  If that works, update and upgrade.  If that doesn't work, look in /var/log/syslog immediately after restarting Network Manager and look for errors.

Comment: Sorry for the late response,i  did not have acces to the internet in the past few days,your first recommendation solved my problem,i even changed my router and everything has been working fine.