# 14.04 - Network manager stopped working

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, network-manager

When I started my laptop, there was **no network service**, and also **no network icon in the top bar**. It gives an error when I start OS like **"Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 experienced an internal error"**. When I click details, it says the error is occurred in the executable path `usr/sbin/NetworkManager`. Also, when I try to enter `Network` in the `System Settings`, it says **"the system network services are not compatible with this version"**

How can I solve this shocking issue?

p.s. I didn't install any third party packages/apps related with networking. Only system updates are installed.

Comment: fyi: a new issue has been opened on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1581535

Comment: I'm on a wired connection, and the [solution posted in a different Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/q/772412/38585) solved it for me.

Comment: The fixed packages seems to have been uploaded to `trusty-updates`: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1511735

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I got the same problem today.

TLDR: downgrade `libnl3` or upgrade `network-manager`.

As per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/727462), problem is that a fix in `libnl3` caused a regression in `network-manager`. Then, it was only a bug for `-proposed` packages, but I guess bug was tested enough that it could be introduced into regular Ubuntu ;).

Safest way is to take a step back and install earlier versions of `libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200` (see details in said answer).

This leaves you with downgraded packages. Remember to not upgrade them until relevant upgrade for `network-manager` is available.

Alternatively (I did this), you can take a step ahead and install newer version of `network-manager`:
for [amd64](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3_amd64.deb) or for [i386](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3_i386.deb). You can download package on different system and pass it with USB stick. Or download it with your smartphone and pass it via USB.

Install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i network-manager_*.deb
```

You can try to get networking by just restarting NetworkManager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But I needed to reboot to get systray applet back.

Comment: so, do we (14.04) need to avoid network manager updates now?

Comment: My system is not getting connected to ethernet... So how will i update the network manager? Moreover the command line that u gave for updating network manager is not working

Comment: @RichaTibrewal Download them on other OS/PC and pass via USB stick. That's what I did. I fixed the typo in the command as well.

Comment: It's also instructive to mention that the `trusty-proposed` updates should be turned off so as not to allow the version incompatibility that causes this in the first place, as detailed on the page that @tamkderplar linked to.

Comment: @UserName i never had trusty-proposed turned on, but got affected by regular updates yesterday.

Comment: I never had trusty-proposed updates checked on any of my 5 lab machines either (all 14.04.4), yet I too was impacted by the problem.   A major THANK YOU for the resolution, they are all marked as "hold".  Now I wonder, how will we be notified when it is ok to update the libraries?

Comment: @DennisJ My guess would be whenever update for `network-manager` to version `0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3` is presented by Software Updater. In fact, just now, I regularly updated my laptop (also Ubuntu machine), because that update was on the list, and network still works after the reboot.

Comment: Thanks for this. Saved the day for me. I am shocked that something like this (virtually bricking an installation)  can move from proposed to live, after it was repeatedly flagged as broken when in proposed.

I love Linux, and Ubuntu, but whenever something like this happens I am reminded of why I can't recommend it to my parents (i.e. non tech users) just yet :(

Comment: +1 After few failed attempts and almost getting the feel _oh no, should I reinstall (last one was like month ago)_ this worked like a charm. I did also the alternative approach (download NM elsewhere and run from flashdisk).

Comment: Manually upgrading or downgrading packages is generally bad advice in a system like Ubuntu or Debian.

Answer (score 9):

This method works if you can connect by Ethernet cable.

Use Ubuntu's built in recovery mode to upgrade Network Manager.

#### Step 1

Use the down-arrow key to select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Step 2

Use down-arrow key to select the latest Linux kernel with Recovery Mode and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I used **Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-36-generic (recovery mode)**

#### Step3

Use down-arrow key to select **network  Enable Networking** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Step 4

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for **OK** to remount the file system

[image: Step 1 to 4 screenshots]

#### Step 5

Use the down-arrow key to select **dpkg  Repair Broken packages** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Step 6

It will ask to download the latest Network Manager with **Continue [Y/n]**. Input letter y for "yes" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
When all operations have finished it will say

> Finished. Please press Enter

So press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

#### Step 7

Select **resume Resume normal boot** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Step 8

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and continue to boot. At the login screen DO NOT log in instead do a NORMAL restart (click shutdown icon at the top right area of the screen).

After the PC restarts then log in.

Network connections were back when I did these steps.

[image: Step 5 to 8 screenshots]

Comment: This only works with an ethernet connection.

Comment: Thanks! This worked!! It's too much of a surprise to get your OS lose network after update.

Comment: When i select network enable networking... I get modemmanager is shut down

Comment: I also got a "Modem Manager is shut down" and the system was stuck to that. I then connected my ethernet cable and it started to work again after a few seconds.

Comment: @RichaTibrewal I suggest you follow the steps suggested in [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)

Comment: Do @alexandru.topliceanu

Comment: This did not work for me. The process sort of stopped after clicking "Yes" in the fourth step. It show some log (don't remember what exactly some "_blocking_" and "XX/YY". I've let that for almost 30 mins sit and nothing. [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/771692/194703) worked first time.

Comment: Ditto; my PC sort of hung at step 4 too. However, [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/772324/103266) did work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way to fix the problem:

Download file:

- libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_XXX.deb
- libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_XXX.deb
- libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_XXX.deb

  OS 32bit: XXX = i386 ||
  OS 64bit: XXX = amd64

Link:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/

To them into one folder and install them with the command:

> sudo dpkg -i lib*.deb

Then Reboot.
Done :3

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend downgrading packages or installing new ones by hand - this will inevitably lead to version issues later on. The best fix to this issue is simply to upgrade the `network-manager` package.

The first thing to do is to connect manually to the internet; while the `network-manager` is dead this does not mean you can not connect.

**1**. Open a terminal and edit the `interfaces` file:

`sudo pico /etc/network/interfaces`

There add the following lines, they indicate the `eth0` interface should no longer be managed:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**2**. With this the connection can be started manually:

`sudo ifup eth0`

Note that there will be no notification in the panel - this is a manual connection. Give it a try with `ping` or firing up your internet browser.

**3**. Now update the `apt` meta-data:

`sudo apt-get update`

And upgrade the `network-manager` package:

`sudo apt-get upgrade network-manager`

**4**. Make sure you now have version `0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3` installed:

`apt-cache show network-manager`

**5**. Now edit again the `interfaces` file and remove or comment the lines added in step 1.:

`sudo pico /etc/network/interfaces`

**6**. Finally reboot the system.