# lost wireless internet connection following update and reboot

Tags: networking, wireless, updates

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 AMD64 on an ASUS laptop and ran the updates today, May 13.  When I later turned the computer back on, there was no internet and no little wireless icon on the desktop.  I tried an ethernet cable and that didn't work, either.  I am now using another computer on the same wireless network, so I know the problem is in the computer and, given the timing, probably the result of the update.  Trusty-proposed is not checked in the software updater.  How can I recover the internet connection?  The wireless adapter is Qualcomm Atheros AR9485. The ethernet interface is a Realtek RTLL8111/8168/8411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue; see [14.04 - Network manager stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771627/14-04-network-manager-stopped-working/771692) (among others) and the "critical" Ubuntu bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1581535 for more information.

I'm sorry you have to deal with this -- it shouldn't have happened in the first place -- but hopefully one of the workarounds will work for you, and Canonical/Ubuntu should be releasing a fix soon.

Comment: I was able to get back online by updating the network manager as described in http://askubuntu.com/questions/771627/14-04-network-manager-stopped-working/771692.  Thanks for your help and especially for your sympathy.