# Latest Ubuntu Update Affects Networking in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, firefox, internet, mail

I installed the latest Ubuntu updates this morning, May 14, 2016 on two installations hosted by VirtualBox (4.3.28 on one machine and 5.0.20 on a second machine).  After the Ubuntu update, the two machines will not connect to the internet.

Typing `ifconfig` on the two machines only provides one interface:  `127.0.0.1`.

Both of these machines were able to connect to the internet immediately before the Ubuntu upgrade.

I have checked a third Ubuntu installation on one of the hosts (4.3.28) and it is still able to connect to the internet. This third installation has not been updated to the latest Ubuntu updates.

Because VirtualBox and the third, non-upgraded Ubuntu installation are still working, it appears that the Ubuntu installation did something to affect network connectivity.

Attempting to start Firefox leads to:

`Server not found  Firefox can't find the server at start.ubuntu.com`

Mail is also down.

This could be nasty if the upgrade is cutting the installs off from the internet!

Comment: What are these VMs hosted on?

Comment: The VirtualBox 4.3.28 installation is hosted on a Windows 7 box.    The VirtualBox 5.0.20 is hosted on a different Windows 10 box.  Both boxes are HP laptops.

Comment: My VMs (which I didn't have this problem with) are hosted on an Ubuntu box. Perhaps that is important.

Comment: The thing is that the only upgrade this morning was an Ubuntu upgrade.  Nothing else changed and that's why I'm wondering about the Ubuntu upgrade stepping on something.

Comment: Possible duplicate (related to last updates) : http://askubuntu.com/questions/771627

Comment: Yes.  The solution on the link that worked to fix the problem was:     

Download file:

    libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_XXX.deb
    libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_XXX.deb

    libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_XXX.deb

    OS 32bit: XXX = i386 || OS 64bit: XXX = amd64

Link: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/

To them into one folder and install them with the command:

    sudo dpkg -i lib*.deb

Then Reboot.

This fixed the problem on both machines.  This question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to: 
Launch VirtualBox Manager -> select the correct Operating-System -> Settings -> Network -> Attached to: Bridged Adapter

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.  Unfortunately, these are the VBox settings:  Attached to:  Bridged Adapter,  Name: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN   Adapter Type: Intel PRO/100 MT Desktop (82540EM)   Promiscuous Mode:  Allow VMs   Cable Connected is checked.     I have also tried Promiscuous Mode:  Deny and Cable Connected unchecked.     I have rebooted the Virtual Machine a few times.  But nothing is working yet.