# what happened to my network connection

Tags: networking, connection

I have a dsesktop pc, I am dual booting ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7. after recently doing a software update I can't access my network for Internet, using ubuntu. Windows Internet explorer still can access the net with the same router and DSL modem, I am using firefox as my browser in ubuntu. when I click the firefox icon on the esktop I get an error message that says server not found. In system settings under network a message appears saying the system network services are not compatible with this version.

How can I regain my network connection in ubuntu?

Thanks for any help,
harlie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [14.04 - Network manager stopped working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/771627/14-04-network-manager-stopped-working)

Comment: the process of doing the recovery mode worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in the [linked answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/771692/543431).

However, in your case you'll need to download the .deb under Windows, copy it to a USB stick, reboot into Ubuntu and copy and install the .deb from the USB stick.