# Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade turned my internet off?

Tags: wireless

I have an HP laptop 7 months old (10 inch screen) I have been running Ubuntu on it for 6 months without any problems, yesterday the upgrade for Ubuntu 16-04 appeared which  I eagerly accepted, after completing the download and set up I have 16-04 but sadly my internet is now disabled,I've tried  the obvious things and some fixes on this site but to no avail. 
Any one out there who can help ??????

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/779465/edit) your question to include terminal results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsmod | grep wmi`

Comment: Haven't a clue what all that means Jeremy31.

Comment: Open a terminal window using CTRL + ALT +t  enter the command, press enter.  The use mouse or touchpad to highlight results.  Use right click menu to copy

Comment: Jeremy31 
ray@ray-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ 1spci -nnk | grep -ia2 net; 1smod | grep wmi -
No command '1spci' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lspci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
1spci: command not found
No command '1smod' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lsmod' from package 'kmod' (main)
1smod: command not found
ray@ray-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$

Comment: The commands have a small L in them, not a 1

Comment: Jeremy31 Sorry here it is again.

Comment: ray@ray-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsmod | grep wmi -
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
 Kernel modules: bcma, wl
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  20 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda

Comment: _codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
ray@ray-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$

Comment: You likely have Secure Boot enable in BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a wireless connection?

If yes, used this tutorial to solve my problem.

https://askubuntu.com/a/771841/517454

(I did it after an upgrade in 14.04, but maybe it can work in your case too.)

Comment: Thanks Emile but this didn't work.