# No internet connection, how to restore to default

Tags: networking, internet

I have no internet, no icon, and just nothing. This maybe was after few manipulations when i was trying to solve problems with usb modem, which wasn't working properly, which i did a long ago. And now after month later i started my ubuntu, and Currently my ubuntu have no internet connection, on windows internet works fine, can't uninstall ubuntu because there is a lot of staff. `ifconfig` shows:

```
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:115214 (115.2 KB) TX bytes:115214 (115.2 KB)
```

`All Settings -> Network` Showing Error Message "**The system network services are not compatible with this version**"

What is wrong, how can i fix this, Have no idea on how to fix this, Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, actually one line of code did the job `gksu "service network-manager start"` from answer [@hexafraction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129436/restarted-computer-during-update-the-system-network-service-is-not-compatible)